# WPF : Set child window size programmatically

Tags: c#, wpf, resize

I need to resize a child window when its parent is resized manually.
In order to do this, I made the following code on the parent window :

```
SizeChanged += (sender, e) =>
{
    if (e.PreviousSize.Width != 0 && e.PreviousSize.Height != 0)
    {
        m_RatioX *= e.NewSize.Width / e.PreviousSize.Width;
        m_RatioY *= e.NewSize.Height / e.PreviousSize.Height;
    }
    WPFWindow p = ((WPFWindow)sender);
    foreach (WPFWindow w in p.OwnedWindows)
    {
        if (w.m_doStretch)
        {
            // this work fine
            w.Left *= m_RatioX / w.m_RatioX;
            w.Top *= m_RatioY / w.m_RatioY;
            w.Canvas.RenderTransform = new ScaleTransform(m_RatioX, m_RatioY);

            // but not for the size modification
            w.Width *= m_RatioX / w.m_RatioX;
            w.Height *= m_RatioY / w.m_RatioY;
            w.m_RatioX = m_RatioX;
            w.m_RatioY = m_RatioY;
        }
    }
};
```

The lines

```
w.Width *= m_RatioX / w.m_RatioX;
w.Height *= m_RatioY / w.m_RatioY;
```

does not works in the sense that they have absolutely no effect on the child window size.

After some researchs I've also tried the following two alternatives, but the first also has no effect on the window size where the second crash with a `NullReferenceException`.

```
// first alternative
Window.GetWindow(w).Width = Window.GetWindow(w).Width * m_RatioX / w.m_RatioX;
Window.GetWindow(w).Height = Window.GetWindow(w).Height * m_RatioY / w.m_RatioY;

// second one
Application.Current.MainWindow = w;
Application.Current.MainWindow.Width = Application.Current.MainWindow.Width * m_RatioX / w.m_RatioX;
Application.Current.MainWindow.Height = Application.Current.MainWindow.Height * m_RatioY / w.m_RatioY;
```

So, how should I modify the size of the child window so that its render is effectively resized ?

**EDIT :**

Some precisions :

- The `SizeChanged` handler is called only in the parent window.
- `m_RatioX` and `m_RatioY` default values are 1.

Comment: I checked your original code (without the two alternatives) and it seems to work fine. Two things that you need to check: 1.) It only works if the values of `m_RatioX` and `m_RatioY` are never `0d`. What are the initial values in your case? 2.) Are you subscribing the `SizeChanged` only in the parent window or also in the child window(s)? If you are handling the `SizeChanged` in the child windows too then the effects will cascade in a strange optical way.

Comment: And another observation: What is causing the `NullReferenceException` in your second alternative? If `w` is null then you have a more general problem.

Comment: I made some edit on the first message to clarify some points. Also, the `NullReferenceException` is raised when trying to affect `w` to `Application.Current.MainWIndow`, but `w` is not `null` (of that I'm sure).

Comment: If you layout your top level window correctly, using correct layout containers and not hard-coded sizes, you don't need to do any of this. Child will resize automatically with the parent. Don't use fixed sizes on controls!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I've found a solution.
Instead of using the Width/Height properties directly, one should use the related `DependencyProperty`.
i.e., use `w.SetValue(Window.WidthProperty, <value>);` instead of `w.Width = <value>`.